# why can't Volley String request send Body parameters with POST method in x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: android, post, android-volley

First of all, I should say that I read several similar stories here, but none of them solved my problem of receiving 400 error code.
I wanna send some login information to server in android studio 3.3.1 and volley library using Post method. I send params as key-value in getBody, and set content type in getBodyContentType().
server only gets params in xxx-form-urlencoded format. I use Postman as proxy to see what is sending...
parameters are received by postman in Body in raw format not in xxx-form-urlencoded, and I think this is why server cant get login parameters and I receive 400 error code (BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400)-
btw server is written in asp.net and IIS webserver.

```
 private  void PostParams()
        {
             Boolean is_valid_user;
            try {

                String URL = "http://192.168.43.22:5555/AOBServices/login";
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                jsonBody.put("my_very_special_key","Love");
                jsonBody.put("username", "amir");
                jsonBody.put("password", "1234");
                jsonBody.put("grant_type", "password");
                final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
                final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "SUCCESSSSSSSSSSSSS \n response: "+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //update shared prefs.....
                        myResponse=response;
                        shprefs= new sharedPrefsClass(getApplicationContext());
                        shprefs.setDefaults("USER_ID", mEmail);
                        shprefs.setDefaults("IS_SIGNEDIN", true);
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        // As of f605da3 the following should work
                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                        if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                            try {
                                String res = new String(response.data,
                                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));

                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                                // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }


                }) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

                    }
                    @Override
                    protected String getParamsEncoding() {
                        return "utf-8";
                    }


                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                                 return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");

                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                                 return null;
                        }
                    }

                 @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        String responseString = "";
                        if (response != null) {
                            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                            // can get more details such as response.headers
                        }
                        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    }
                };

                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Zoe You're right. Thank you for teaching this point to me. This is my first experience in SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those facing similar problem:
after getting disappointed of Volley, I implemented network stuff by `HttpUrlConnection`, and found out what the problem is:
I was sending parameters in json object format i.e {key:value,...} while server expected key:value&key:value&...
so returned to Volley and made parameter string like above and use it in `getBody()`, solved my problem. :)